# Multiple objects with same FK in context.entity.local [Entity Framework]

Tags: database, frameworks, save, entity, local

I have some problems regarding entity framework and saving to the db.

As my current program works, it deserializes a json-object which results in a list with objects that matches the database. Each of these objectst looks like this:

- Every object is a parent with a relation to one child-object.
- Each child object have a relation to one or many parent-objects.

After the deserialization is complete each child-objects is created as new object for every parent (meaning I get several instances of the same object).

When i try to save the objects to the db, this offcourse doesn't work since I'm trying to insert many child-objects whith the same pk. I can clearly see that context.childentity.local contains many objects with the same pk.

Is there any easy way to solve this issue? Can I in some way tell EF to refer all duplicates to the same object?

Best regards Anton